# Can't download web photo albums to Picasa

Tags: firefox, protocol, google-picasa

Someone has shared a Picasa web album (Limited, anyone with the link), but I can't download it to Picasa. The following alert appears:

> Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol
>   (picasa) isn't associated with any program.

I have Picasa 3.0.0 installed on Ubuntu 11.04, I remember it saying something about registering the picasa protocol with Firefox during the installation.

I have Firefox 6.0.2, and these settings are present in *about:config*

> network.protocol-handler.app.picasa;/usr/bin/picasa
>   network.protocol-handler.expose.picasa;true
>   network.protocol-handler.external.picasa;true

Picasa is located here:

> $ which picasa
>   /usr/bin/picasa

Is there something I can do to make this work?

PS: I hope this is not off-topic here, and I can't find the "picasa" tag.
Could someone please add it, if appropriate?

Comment: Reinstalling the Picasa application did not help...

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem with Picasa 2.7, Ubuntu 10.4 LTS, Firefox 3.6.23. In about:config, I have: network.protocol-handler.app.picasa;/usr/bin/picasa
network.protocol-handler.external.picasa;true $ which picasa
/usr/bin/picasa

Comment: Somehow I have the feeling that the solution will involve MIME types.

Answer (score 2):

I added a new mimetype to make it works

http://www.ajopaul.com/2011/08/07/ubuntu-fix-for-firefox-to-download-picasa-albums/
Worked for me :)

> Open firefox tab and type about:config
>
> ```
> set network.protocol-handler.expose.picasa to false
> set network.protocol-handler.external.picasa to true
> set network.protocol-handler.app.picasa
> ```
>
> to either /usr/bin/picasa or /opt/picasa/bin/picasa (/usr/bin/picasa
>   is a symlink to /opt/xxx)
>
> If the above doesn’t work for you then try the method which was
>   mentioned in this post. It was originally meant as a fix for chrome,
>   but works fine with firefox too.
>
> Open the file ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list (remember to
>   back it up) and add the following under [Added Associations]
>
> ```
> x-scheme-handler/picasa=picasa.desktop
> ```
>
> Thats it. Now choose “Download to Picasa”, you will get a popup to
>   choose the picasa application, here browse until the location of the
>   picasa binary. /opt/google/picasa/3.0/bin/picasa in my case

Comment: This does open Picasa when I click on a "Download to Picasa" link, but nothing happens afterwards, and I don't see any activity or an import screen/prompt.